# I need assistance with splitting and making an output file in Python

Tags: python

I need help to make a practice program for myself. It requires splitting and finding a specific string in a text file and then outputting it on another text file. 
I need to find every record with a date over 1979 and output all the records found into an output file. How would I do this?

This is how part of the txt file looks like:

```
Fake Brothers,GLOUCESTER CITY,NJ,8030,4/17/1980,380074088725856,7241
Quark Industries,STERLING HEIGHTS,MI,48314,7/1/1985,4738660574375490,2636
Globo-Chem,POWAY,CA,92064,8/31/1943,6011241197713964,7927
```

Comment: 1st of January? or 31st of December? BTW you have a strange hobby splitting files.

Comment: Well so far:
def main():

    infile = open('tranz.txt', 'r')

    contents = infile.read()

    search = contents.split(',')

Comment: @Gene: Please don't add comments to your own question.  It's your question.  Please update the question to include the code you've written.  And please be very specific on what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want something that works:

```
for line in text:
    date = line.split(',')[3]
    year = int(date.split('/')[2])
```

If you want do be more exacting and extensible, you may want to look into the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module.
I assume you can do the reading and writing bits.

Comment: There appears to be only one line in the above input.

Comment: And he changed the above input. So there you go.